# how do I to fix this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

Tags: hibernate, session, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to include Hibernate technology in my project but I got this stack trace and I don't know how to fix it. Any help please ?

Here is my stack trace, **I got these two errors :** :

> SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
>   SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier. SLF4J: Upgrade your
>   binding to version 1.6.x. or 2.0.x
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.forum.utils.HibernateUtils
>         at com.forum.dao.UtilisateurDAO.create(UtilisateurDAO.java:20)
>         at com.forum.form.InscriptionForm.inscrireUtilisateur(InscriptionForm.java:66)
>         at com.forum.servlets.Inscription.doPost(Inscription.java:32)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Here is my **HibernateUtils.class**

> public class HibernateUtils {
>
> ```
>   private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
>
>   static {
>       try {
>           sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
>                   .buildSessionFactory();
>       } catch (HibernateException ex) {
>           throw new RuntimeException("Problème de configuration : "
>                   + ex.getMessage(), ex);
>       }
>   }
>
>   public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
>       return sessionFactory.openSession();
>   }
> }
> ```

Here is **UtilisateurDAO.java:20** line :

> s = HibernateUtils.getSession();

**Here is Hibernate3.0 library and my jstl jars** :
[image]

Comment: add this line to the top of your class  package com.forum.util;

Comment: I haven't wrote the imported packages to do not clutter the content

Comment: package statement is not there and there is a difference between package and import statement

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` possibly means that one dependency of `HibernateUtils` is not available: So check that for each `import` there is really a .jar in the classpath of your webapp (recursively) which contains that class. Please add all `imports` of `HibernateUtils` to your question, and also the list of jars you include in your webapp. Have you packaged hibernate.jar into your webapp?

Comment: `Could not initialize class com.forum.utils.HibernateUtils at` - this typically means that the code in your static block ran into some exception. But the stack trace you posted does not seem to be complete. Typically there is a `Caused by` section below this top level stack trace that actually describes the root cause in detail. That would more likely contain the real cause.

Comment: Do you have different versions of some jars related to Hibernate in your webapp and in tomcat, especially the log4j stuff?

Comment: nope, I have only the 3rd version of Hibernate, the final jars (distribution, annotations).

Comment: Can you clean your project and rebuild and try ?

Comment: What is your environment ? How have you setup this app ? And yes, clean and rebuild your project and redploy in tomcat.

Comment: Eclipse, i'm programming it. The problem about Hibernate lib I think, not how setting it up, isn't it ?